# Error Message of ResponsStatus should not be null when error is thrown and message is provided

Tags: c#, .net, rest, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack and I am having trouble getting back the error message in the ResponseStatus when an error is thrown.

My service Requests/Responses are named according to the naming convention required by ServiceStack.

REQUEST:

```
namespace DataDictionary.ServiceModel
{
    // Create the name of the Web Service (i.e. the Request DTO)
    [RestService("/receivables/{id}", "GET")]
    [RestService("/years/{year}/processes/{processname}/receivables/{name}", "GET")]
    [DataContract]    
    public class ReceivableRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int year { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string processname { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
namespace DataDictionary.ServiceModel
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ReceivableRequestResponse : IHasResponseStatus
    {
        public ReceivableRequestResponse()
        {
            this.ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Uri process { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Uri year { get; set; }

        #region IHasResponseStatus Members

        [DataMember]
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus {get; set;}

        #endregion
    }
}
```

SERVICE:

```
namespace DataDictionary.ServiceInterface
{
    // Create the Web Service implementation 
    public class ReceivableService : RestServiceBase<ReceivableRequest>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Receivable> m_receivableRepository;

        public ReceivableService(IRepository<Receivable> receivableRepository)
        {
            m_receivableRepository = receivableRepository;
        }

        public override object OnGet(ReceivableRequest request)
        {
            if (request != null && request.id > 0)
            {
                return GetSpecificReceivable(request.id);
            }            
        }

        private object GetSpecificReceivable(int id)
        {
            Receivable receivable = m_receivableRepository.SingleOrDefault(rec => rec.Id == id);
            if (receivable != null)
            {
                return receivable;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new ArgumentException(string.Format("Could not find receivable with id {0}.", id)));
            }        
        }        
    }
}
```

The error message is returned when I unit test the service

```
[Test]
public void Can_GET_Receivable_Not_Found_Successfully()
{
    //given
    var year = new Year { Name = 2006 };

    IRepository<Year> repository = Kernel.Get<IRepository<Year>>();
    repository.Add(year);

    var process = new Process { Name = "TEST", Year = year };
    year.AddProcess(process);

    var receivable = new Receivable { Name = "File1" };
    process.AddReceivable(receivable);

    repository.Update(year);

    var service = Kernel.Get<ReceivableService>();
    var request = new ReceivableRequest { year = 2011, processname = "TEST", name = "File1" };

    //when
    try
    {
        var entity = (Receivable)service.OnGet(request);
    }
    //then
    catch (HttpError e)
    {
        e.Message.ShouldEqual("Could not find receivable File1 from process TEST in year 2011.");
        e.StatusCode.ShouldEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

However, when I send requests using fiddler, I would expect the error message to be returned in the JSON, 
The status code 404 is available but there is no error message.

How can I get access to the error message?

Comment: Same problem.  I have no idea why my error messages aren't coming through.  This is extremely frustrating.